# What port is used on the client machine to send messages to rabbitmq?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I have created a small class for demonstration purpose that sends a message to rabbitmq on a specific port:

```
class RabbitMqPublisher
{
    private IAdvancedBus _advancedBus;
    public RabbitMqPublisher()
    {
        _advancedBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=rabbitmq-server:5672;virtualHost=/;username=user;password=pass").Advanced;
    }

    public void PublishMessage(string message)
    {
        var routingKey = "SimpleMessage";

        // declare some objects
        var queue = _advancedBus.QueueDeclare("TestQueue.SimpleMessage");
        var exchange = _advancedBus.ExchangeDeclare("TestExchange.SimpleMessage", ExchangeType.Direct);
        var binding = _advancedBus.Bind(exchange, queue, routingKey);

        _advancedBus.Publish(exchange, routingKey, true, new Message<string>(message));
    }
}
```

In this case the port on which the RabbitMQ server is waiting for messages is **5672**. My question is besides that, ***what port is used by the client to send this message***, and would it be possible to configure it?

Comment: "_what port is used by the client to send this message?_" I believe that is not the responsibility of your client software, but rather it is dynamically assigned by whatever underlying network layer creates the client-side socket connection - and that software chooses an available port number dynamically from the client's list of unreserved ports. In other words, its not something you or RabbitMQ have any direct control over - and it does not matter what that port number is.  (I am not a network expert, I confess.) Is there a reason why you might want to configure it?

Comment: I'm afraid it's similar with [http client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400958/what-port-does-httpclient-use).

Comment: @andrewJames that's because let's say I want to deploy a rabbitmq client app on a server, and I don't want to open all of the ports on that server, more like a security concern

Comment: @TinyWang do you have any documentation in relation to this?

Comment: no. but we just need to check if it's through http protocol I think..

Answer (score 0):

**15672** FROM HTTP API CLIENT

Port Access

Firewalls and other security tools may prevent RabbitMQ from binding to a port. When that happens, RabbitMQ will fail to start. Make sure the following ports can be opened:

4369: epmd, a peer discovery service used by RabbitMQ nodes and CLI tools

5672, 5671: used by AMQP 0-9-1 and 1.0 clients without and with TLS

25672: used by Erlang distribution for inter-node and CLI tools communication and is allocated from a dynamic range (limited to a single port by default, computed as AMQP port + 20000). See networking guide for details.

**15672**: HTTP API clients and rabbitmqadmin (only if the management plugin is enabled)

61613, 61614: STOMP clients without and with TLS (only if the STOMP plugin is enabled)

1883, 8883: (MQTT clients without and with TLS, if the MQTT plugin is enabled

15674: STOMP-over-WebSockets clients (only if the Web STOMP plugin is enabled)

15675: MQTT-over-WebSockets clients (only if the Web MQTT plugin is enabled)

Reference doc: https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows-manual.html

Comment: for me it seems this page is about server side RabbitMQ node rather than the port on the client machines... I've found this as well, but I didn't went to the end yet https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html